# How can i extract feature from 9 image in one matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have 9 images  and I want to extract features from every images and make a matrix  that contain features for all images  along row in the matrix containing features for one image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention which feature you want to calculate. Assuming you have function `func(I)` for calculating feature given an image.

Assume `I` contains all `9` images. So the dimension of `I` is `(512,512,9)`.

```
feature = zeros(9, dim_feature);
parfor i = 1:size(I,3)
    feature(i,:) = func(I(:,:,i));
end
```

Comment: sorry i want to extract color feature  and how can i read 9 image at one time

Comment: may  i have your  email address to contact with you  because  i have a lot of question @Avijit Dasgupta

Comment: avijit9.github.io (not posting email id here. go to website and get the email id)